# "We want someone who has the utmost attention to detail." is this usage correct?

Tags: grammar

> We want someone who has the utmost attention to detail.

I've not come across this before. Usually one pays attention to detail and has the ability to attend to details, can one have attention to detail? Why does this sound ungrammatical?

Comment: *Why does this sound ungrammatical?* It doesn't to me. It probably sounds strange to you as you have not encountered it before. Have a look at the website Performance Education *Your Attention to Detail?* https://www.performance.edu.au/blog/how-can-you-develop-your-attention-detail

Comment: *Someone* ***who has***, *someone* ***with***, and *someone* ***who pays*** are all idiomatic in this construction.